# Box Issue when "Deny Access" is selected in Box window(frame)

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am integrating Box.com with my application. My flow is when the employee login for the very first time, he will be presented with Box Page in an frame (Please note  I am not using Box Embed Widgt as such).

After entering the valid username and password in box page, then user wil be taken to another page, where he can select "access to box" or "Deny Access".

Now my issue is when I click on Deny Access nothing happens, I get a blank screen. When debug it reaches my application back and but nothing happens.

Could you please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the user clicks deny, then Box will call your redirect URI (on your server) with

You will receive a GET request at

`https://www.yourServer.com/someendpoint?error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+access+to+your+application`

You will need to handle that response, and know that the user decided they did not want to use your application.

Answer (score 0):

You do get a notification of the denial via the page registered with Box.

When you register your application with Box you provide a page (your page) that will be called when the oAuth completes.

This is explained in this tutorial: http://developers.box.com/oauth/

Look particularly at this section:

Authorization Code: The authorization code is only valid for 30 seconds.
However, if the user clicked Deny, you will receive a request with an error and error_description parameter, such as:

GET https://www.sean.com/rose?error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+access+to+your+application